# How to find the associated service account for Helm?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, service-accounts

Prior to Helm 3, it was possible to associate a service account in helm initialization via

```
helm init --service-account tiller
```

But since `helm init` is now deprecated, how can we find out which service account is the Helm associated with?

Comment: Users can [authenticate](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/authentication/) in a number of ways so won't always be tied to a service account now. They will have Role/ClusterRole bindings though. `kc auth can-i --list` might be useful too.

Comment: ...and `kc` === `kubectl` in my aliased world

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Helm 3 will have the same permissions according to the default config in `~/.kube/config` or another config if specified in your system environment variable `$KUBECONFIG` or overridden using the following command options

```
      --kube-context string              name of the kubeconfig context to use
      --kubeconfig string                path to the kubeconfig file
```

> With Tiller gone, the security model for Helm is radically simplified. Helm 3 now supports all the modern security, identity, and authorization features of modern Kubernetes. Helm’s permissions are evaluated using your `kubeconfig` file. Cluster administrators can restrict user permissions at whatever granularity they see fit. — [Changes since Helm 2: Removal of Tiller](https://helm.sh/docs/faq/#removal-of-tiller)